# moderator intervention notifications

Tags: feature-request, moderation

Is it possible to get notification when moderators delete content - comments, questions, answers, etc - of content providers?  I don't necessarily mind my content being deleted if it's not meeting the forum's standard, but there is no notification when content is deleted by moderators.  I would prefer an e-mail, but inbox notification is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way to generate a notification that I know of.

I think this query will list your deleted questions and answers, you can run this whenever you like:

- https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a19249%20deleted%3a1&searchOn=3

That user ID (19249) identifies your account.
Most users can see their own deleted posts, but not other users'.

Moderators can also see deleted comments, but I don't know that other users can, not even their own.

---

Yes, I searched another site's meta-site ...

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted+comments

... and found topics there like these ...

- [Ability to see own deleted comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290923/ability-to-see-own-deleted-comments)
- [Please notify users when their comment is deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255137/please-notify-users-when-their-comment-is-deleted)

... which confirm that users can't see their own deleted comments and aren't notified if a comment is deleted.

Instead I should have searched the main meta-site here:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted+comments

... but that says much the same thing, for example:

- [Let us view our deleted comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187279/let-us-view-our-deleted-comments)

Comment: thanks..not really what i'm looking for...i guess notification via inbox or something like that would have been the thing..oh well.